# how to filter list by type in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list, with elements of some Node type, which may be either UNode or LNode or RNode

```
[
    UNode("a"), LNode("b"), RNode("c")
]
```

How can I filter it by the type ( UNode for example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the simplest way is also the only way, as far as I’m aware: match.

```
let isUNode node =
    case node of
        UNode _ -> True
        _ -> False
in filter isUNode
```

Comment: This can be written more succinctly as `let isUNode UNode = True; isUNode _ = False in filter isUNode`. There's no need to use a `case` expression.

Comment: @AaditMShah: In cases where `isUNode` is a longer name, this is shorter, and I don’t like repeating it. That’s all.

Answer (score 14):

List comprehensions seem useful here:

```
[ x | x@(Unode _) <- list ]
```